# Channels-redis wont install using pip

Tags: python, django, redis, pip

im trying to install channels-redis using `pip install -U pip channels-redis` but it cause the following error:

**Error:**

```
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for hiredis, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: hiredis, async-timeout, aioredis, channels-redis
  Running setup.py install for hiredis ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for hiredis did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      C:\Users\APA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lvqc1hfx\hiredis_65bd53516444439e81ff8540ee5b60d1\setup.py:7: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in 
favour of importlib and slated for removal in Python 3.12; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
        import sys, imp, os, glob, io
      C:\Users\APA\Desktop\KM-APP\KM\Repo\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:771: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running install
      C:\Users\APA\Desktop\KM-APP\KM\Repo\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use 
build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hiredis
      copying hiredis\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hiredis
      copying hiredis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hiredis
      copying hiredis\hiredis.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hiredis
      copying hiredis\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\hiredis
      running build_ext
      building 'hiredis.hiredis' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/  
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> hiredis

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

so after this i tried to install hiredis but it gave me the same error then i updated my pip and tried again but its still the same...any solution how to fix this issue ? i also installed wheel thought maybe it will help

Answer (score 0):

The current latest version of `hiredis` 2.0 [provides](https://pypi.org/project/hiredis/2.0.0/#files) wheels for Python 3.6-3.9 but not 3.10 or later. Use lower version of Python.

Or install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 to compile C/C++ extensions.

Answer (score -1):

The current  version of redis does not support Python 3.10
Try using lower versions of python